# Игра в города на питоне с использованием регулярных выражений

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

```
text=("Абакан Азов Александров Алексин Альметьевск Анапа Ангарск\
Анжеро-Судженск Апатиты Арзамас Армавир Арсеньев Артем Архангельск Асбест\
Астрахань Ачинск Балаково Балахна Балашиха Балашов Барнаул Батайск Белгород\
Белебей Белово Белогорск Белорецк Белореченск Бердск Березники Березовский\
Бийск Биробиджан Благовещенск Бор")
done=False
while not(False):
x=input("Enter your city")
S=x[-1]
c=S.title()
patterns=[r'[{}]\S\w+\S'.format(c)]#проблема в этой строчке
for pattern in patterns:
    p=re.search(pattern, text)
    print(p)
    text = re.sub(r'{}',"Этот город уже был",text.format(p))
```

Программа должна спрашивать у пользователя. Получив ответ, выводит город, начинающийся на последнюю букву предыдущего слова. Выведя город, она удаляет его.

Что-то пошло не так в этом варианте программы: вызванный город не удаляется.

По совету друга я изменил строчку на `patterns=[r'[{}]\S\D+\S'.format(c)]`
для того, чтобы программа нормально читала русский язык, однако тут вылезли другие проблемы программа начала выводить сразу несколько городов подряд, к тому же не удаляет эти города.

В связи с этим хочу спросить совета: как изменить код, чтобы город был удален после вызова?

Comment: города сложить не в строку, а в список. Тогда и регулярки не понадобятся.

Comment: В список конечно проще будет, но я хочу сделать через регулярку

Answer (score 2):

Пользуйся на здоровье.

```py
import re

text = (' Абакан Азов Александров Алексин Альметьевск Анапа Ангарск \
Анжеро-Судженск Апатиты Арзамас Армавир Арсеньев Артем Архангельск Асбест \
Астрахань Ачинск Балаково Балахна Балашиха Балашов Барнаул Батайск Белгород \
Белебей Белово Белогорск Белорецк Белореченск Бердск Березники Березовский \
Бийск Биробиджан Благовещенск Бор ')

while True:
    i = input('<<< ').strip().upper()
    if i != '':
        c = i[-1]
        result = re.search(f'\\s[{c}]\\w+\\s', text)
        if result:
            result = result.group(0)
            print('>>> ' + result.strip() ) 
            text = re.sub(result,' <Этот город уже был> ', text)
        else:
            print('>>> Не найдено подходящего города!')
```